# Codeigniter decode not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, encryption, encoding

I am making a little login system using php inside of Codeigniter framework. I using the encryption class to encode a password, store in database. Then on login, finds their encrypted password using their username, then matches it against the password they entered. The passwords ARE getting encoded during registration. And in the below code, I have been able to print out the encoded password from the database, but then it fails out whenever I run it through decode. But no error message, just nothing.

```
public function check_pw(){
    //post username and password to database
    $data['username'] = $this->input->post('username');
    $data['password'] = $this->input->post('password');
    $this->load->model('lindsdata');
    //encoded password returned from database - this is working
    $return_data = $this->lindsdata->password($data);
    //$return_data = $this->encrypt->decode($return_data);  
    //print_r shows $return_data does hold the encrypted password
    //but when I uncomment the line with decode in it, $return_data print_rs nothing. 
    print_r($return_data);
    if ($return_data == $data['password']) {
        redirect('/update/user', 'location');
    }
    if($return_data !== $data['password']){
        //at this point, $return_data of course still has nothing
        print_r($return_data);
        //print_r below is the entered password by user..that shows up.
        print_r($data['password']);
        $error['the_error'] = 'Your Credentials are wrong';
    }else{
        $error['the_error'] = '';
    }
}
```

I tried this below to make sure things were being encoded properly...this returned "test" as expected.

```
 $a = "test";
 $test = $this->encrypt->encode($a); 
 $test = $this->encrypt->decode($test);
 print_r($test);
```

To further confuse me...I originally manually encoded a password (like in the code above) and had put the result in a database with a user (I had not set up a registration form yet, just did that so I had a user to work with)...that one works fine for some reason. None of the other encoded user passwords are working. I don't get why they are failing out during the decode. The database is set to varchar(255). And I am DEFINITELY getting the encoded password when I run it through decode...but then nothing. No error message or anything and very stumped. Thanks it advance. ...and I did not post the model because I don't think it was relevant since that is indeed returning the encoded password for checking as it should.

EDIT - It doesn't make sense $return_data is printing the hash from the DB and $password is returning the proper password but $pw is returning nothing. ...could it be that my SQL database is somehow corrupting/editing my hash? This should work from what I can tell.

```
    $data['username'] = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $this->load->model('lindsdata');
    $return_data = $this->lindsdata->password($data);
    print_r($return_data);
    print_r($password);
    $pw = password_verify($password, $return_data);
    print_r($pw);
```

EDIT - My input to the database is quite simple... I see no reason for that having an issue. ...still failing on either decode or password_verify. Still no idea the problem. It is a simple Mysql database...

```
public function register_submit(){
    $data['user_name'] = $this->input->post('user_name');
    $pwd = $this->input->post('password');
    $data['password'] =  password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $this->load->model('lindsdata');
    $this->lindsdata->register($data);      
}

function register($data){
    $this->db->insert('cred', $data);
}
```

Comment: Cannot produce the problem. Your test code is working fine

Comment: What value is inserted at your database when password is `'test'`;

Comment: test I just did in browser, did not run it through the database. I should try that though.

Answer (score 0):

It is against security practices to directly store a password in the database, even if encrypted. If someone get's access to your server it can take both the code and a snapshot of the database and find out the passwords of all users registered on your site. The best practice regarding passwords is to save a hash of the password (preferably SHA256 or stronger), and compare the hash of the password the user enters in the login form with the one stored in the database. Or, even better, you can use the PHP built in password hashing support (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php).

And indirectly, hashing the password will solve your problem :)

Comment: Ah..after a little reading (I quite fresh to security stuff, I have been using Codeigniter 3rd party library Tank Auth for my needs but decided to create my own login this time). So it looks to me that the difference between encryption and hashing is that hashing has no key. And hashing uses the actually password word (hopefully that made sense) for decryption (in a nutshell). Did I get that right? Going to try this hashing out. Thanks!

Comment: A little confused about this PASSWORD_DEFAULT option though.  - PASSWORD_DEFAULT - Use the bcrypt algorithm (default as of PHP 5.5.0). Note that this constant is designed to change over time as new and stronger algorithms are added to PHP. For that reason, the length of the result from using this identifier can change over time. Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice).  - I don't get what I am storing in the database for this...

Comment: AH. Something must be going on with my database. I did a test outside of database using password_hash and password_verify...just like my $test stuff above. And I got the expected results. But...when I do the same thing but put the hash in the database and then return it, IT IS NOT WORKING! ..I added an edit to my post with some more code.

Comment: My encode/decode stuff should have worked before too from what I can tell...I have basically switched that to the hash stuff and still having the same problem.

Comment: I am still very stuck with this. Is there a setting on my database that could be messing up my encoding? Or codeigniter doing something to the hash?

Comment: If I hash a password, print it out to the browser and manually enter it into the database, IT WORKS! but when I enter it through my code into the database it does not. Seems that Codeigniter does escape db entries, but then I did some could that would prevent it from escaping. This did still not work.

Comment: It fails on password_verify() ...but it is defitinitely getting the password and the hash from the database. ..something must be corrupting the hash when it goes into the database. If I make a hash and print it to browser and then copy and paste that into the database, that hash will work like it is supposed to...something happens to the hash when it goes from my code to database. Still makes no sense to me. I have tried a lot.

Comment: I also printed out the hash before it goes into the database and compared to after it is in db. It is the same.

Comment: Sadly no. I have been working on a different project. I still have this problem. I haven't had a chance to come back to it yet. I will post what I find though when I do.

Comment: I have removed my SELECT statement from Codeigniter functions/syntax and inside my controller I built a SELECT statement using PDO to select the hash from my database and then password_verify...this is working fine. When I register a password, I am still using the codeigniter database functions. So all I can say at this point is something was happening with my SQL SELECT via codeigniter...I can't say what because I still haven't narrowed it down exactly. So at this point, I will be using PDO until I have the time to still pinpoint the problem.